# Print screen area for Dance School ID's?

Tags: c#, screen-capture, image-capture, printscreen

sorry for my bad english. I am new here and to C# also.
I need help with screen capturing a area of the Form that contains image in PictureBox and text in TextBox. Everything is fine except that the saved image of screenshot does not contain the image from PictureBox and the text from TextBox. What am I doing wrong?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;




namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class ID_Editor_Form : Form
    {
        Image File;
        int TogMove; int MValX; int MValY;


        public ID_Editor_Form()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }

        private void pictureBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            TogMove = 1; MValX = e.X; MValY = e.Y;
        }

        private void pictureBox1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            TogMove = 0;
        }

        private void pictureBox1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (TogMove == 1)

            {
                this.SetDesktopLocation(MousePosition.X - MValX, MousePosition.Y - MValY);
            }
        }

        OpenFileDialog BrowseID = new OpenFileDialog();
        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)



        {
            BrowseID.Filter = "JPG|*.jpg|JPEG|*.jpeg|PNG|*.png|All Files|*.*";
            if (BrowseID.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)

            {

                File = Image.FromFile(BrowseID.FileName);
                pictureBox2.Image = File;

            }
        }




        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

        {
            Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(this.Width, this.Height - 48);
            DrawToBitmap(bitmap, new Rectangle(0, 0, bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height));

            bitmap.Save("C:\\Users\\ROBO\\Desktop\\Screen.png", ImageFormat.Png);
            MessageBox.Show("Saved Completed");

         }

     }

}
```

Comment: Only about 10% of the code you posted relates to trying to print the PictureBox. You should edit to remove the other 90%; we're only interested in seeing the *relevant code*.

Comment: Correction: there is no code at all in there that relates to trying to print the picture box. All it does is save an empty png file.